# Using values from strtok to pass into a function

Tags: c, strtok

I have the following code:

```
    char buffer[50];
    char * tok, tok2;
    buffer = "addition 1 2";
    tok = strtok(buffer, " ");
    // get the second token
    tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
    tok2 = tok;
    // get the last token
    tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
    // pass them to the function
    foo(atoi(tok2), atoi(tok));
```

However, I got segmentation fault 11. What I wanted to do is to store the second value (integer 1) and the last value (integer 2) and pass them to foo(int a, int b). How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char * tok, tok2;
```

The above statement defines `tok` to be of type `char *` and `tok2` of type `char`. It's equivalent to

```
char *tok;
char tok2;
```

`char *` is not a new type. You should always associate `*` with the variable, not the type.
You should change that statement to

```
char *tok, *tok2;
```

You cannot assign arrays in `C`. Therefore the following statement is wrong -

```
buffer = "addition 1 2";
```

What you should do is to initialize the array `buffer` with the string literal -

```
char buffer[] = "addition 1 2";
```

Also, note that the function `strtok` modifies its first argument. Its signature is

```
char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);
```

It's for this reason that the first parameter `str` is not `const` qualified unlike the second one `delim`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign a string literal to `buffer` since it is a `char` array, not a `char*` (how did this even compile??).

If you make `buffer` a `char*`, then the assignment will work, but `strtok` will try writing its `NUL` terminators directly into the string literal, which is probably in a read-only region of memory.

Instead, you should use `strcpy(buffer, "addition 1 2");` to copy the read-only string into your read-write `buffer`.

And also what @ajay said...  You should really pay attention to compiler warnings about type mismatches!